# AngularJS getting error on Post method

Tags: html, angularjs

I made an RESTful api in .net .The html is created with angularJS.

The problem is, when the page loads, i'm getting the following error:
[image]

and the "insert" button doesn't work anymore.

This is my insert script and the full html can be found at the link:

```
$scope.insert = function insert() {
        var data = {"id": 3, "name": $scope.name, "description":$scope.description , "price": $scope.price, "categoryid": $scope.categoryid};
        $http.post(
            'http://localhost:22258/api/product',
            JSON.stringify(data),
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        ).success(function (data) {
            $scope.products.push(data);
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0xb2nh9o/

If you are kind to help me to make Edit button works as the following model: https://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/UWLFJ/ to make HTTPPut to api, it will be wonderful.

**All Restful requests works, api works, tested with PostMan**

I'm kinnda newbie to AngularJS so your help will be very useful for me. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert function is part of 'ProductController', not 'FormCtrl'.

So in your html, do this:

```
<div ng-controller="ProductController">
```

and you will get rid of that error.

Answer (score 0):

If you open [the URL reported in the error trace](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=FormCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined) you'll see that angular is complaining about "FormCtrl" being `undefined`.

That's because you named your controller `ProductController` here:

```
app.controller("ProductController", function ($scope, $http) {
```

But required it as `FormCtrl` here:

```
<div ng-controller="FormCtrl">
```

Make those match and that error will go away.

Comment: The insert action now works, but how about table-autorefreshing after completing the Insert ?

Comment: you have a bunch of calls to `localhost`, so that can't be tested from the jsfiddle

Comment: I've got the angular.js:10071TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined error on GetTemplate function

Comment: that's because you never set `$scope.selected` anywhere (you only have a `var selected = {}`, which you push to `$scope.products`, but you never call `$scope.selected = something`). You will have to take it from there, I can't help you debug your app line by line in comments :)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 controllers defined in template, `ProductController` and `FormCtrl`. 
Since **you do not have a Controller definition for formCtrl**, it throws an error.

If you want to keep both of them, define the controller for formCtrl or remove the controller use from the template.